# Could not find or load main class, when run java @options

Tags: java

unable to run and find classpath compiled files CalculatorTest.class, Calculator.class
I think I'm confused about absolute paths...

file options:

```
-d D:\Startjava\out
Calculator.java                                                                                           
CalculatorTest.java
```

file optionsj :

```
-cp D:\Startjava\out
com.starjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.CalculatorTest
```

compile run javac @options

```
D:\Startjava\src\com\startjava\lesson_2_3\calculator (master -> origin)                                                          
λ javac @options                                                                                                                 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

run Could not find or load main class compiled files CalculatorTest.class, Calculator.class.

```
D:\Startjava\src\com\startjava\lesson_2_3\calculator (master -> origin)                                                          
λ java @optionsj                                                                                                                 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8                                                                                
Error: Could not find or load main class com.starjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.CalculatorTest                                       
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.starjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.CalculatorTest
```

source CalculatorTest.java :

```
package com.startjava.lesson_2_3.calculator;

import java.util.*;

public class CalculatorTest {
    public static void  main(String[] args) {
...
}
```

source Calculator.java

```
package com.startjava.lesson_2_3.calculator;

public class Calculator {
...
}
```

file path options optionsj and source :

```
D:\Startjava\src\com\startjava\lesson_2_3\calculator (master -> origin)                                                          
λ ls                                                                                                                             
Calculator.java  CalculatorTest.java  options  optionsj
```

Comment: Your main class is named `com.startjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.CalculatorTest`, but you are trying to run one named `com.starjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.CalculatorTest`.  Note "starjava" != "startjava".

Comment: @JohnBollinger please write it as answer or i will do :)

Comment: I added for clarification, the path options and sources, I am trying to understand your answer

Comment: @Lunatic, the appropriate action, if you should choose to take one, is to vote to close as a typo.  I have not done so myself because I am presently refraining from all moderation actions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it turns out I have an error in the optionsj file, I understand the error in the class name at start, but still not getting the same error

Comment: @JohnBollinger  -cp D:\Startjava\out\com\startjava\lesson_2_3\calculator
CalculatorTest if I write like this in the optionsj file, then the same error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/startjava/lesson_2_3/calculator/CalculatorTest (wrong name: CalculatorTest)

Comment: @Tribjj, the classpath should be `D:\Startjava\out`, not the full path to the class file, so the `options` and `optionsj` files presented in the question appear to be consistent with each other as-is.  The `java` and `javac` commands compute classpath-relative directories for class files based on classes' package names.  You don't do that yourself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger strangely, everything started up for me, as in the beginning the options files, did not change anything, what is it :-d D:\Startjava\out
Calculator.java                                                                                           
CalculatorTest.java   -cp D:\Startjava\out
com.startjava.lesson_2_3.calculator.CalculatorTest and work